# rerendering rich:calendar is not working for the first time but working on page refresh

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a search criteria to fetch details from the database between the two different dates.

I have a h:slectOneMenu populated with the list {"from","to","between"}. For "from" and "to" dates i have to display a rich:calendar to give date input and for "between" i have to display two rich:calendar to give input start date and end date.

My code is like this

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="startdate" 
       value="#{commoncontroller.coverDateType}">  
      <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"     
                   action="#controller.dateSelectionChanged}" 
                   reRender="startdateone,startdatetwo"/>
          <f:selectItems value="#{controller.startDateMap}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

     <h:panelGrid id="startdateone" layout="block" rendered="#{controller.dateOneStatus}">
            <rich:calendar id="date1"                               value="#{controller.covStartDate}" showWeeksBar="false" />
     </h:panelGrid>

     <h:panelGrid id="startdatetwo" layout="block" rendered="#{controller.dateTwoStatus}">
            <rich:calendar id="date2"                               value="#{controller.covStartDate2}" showWeeksBar="false" />
     </h:panelGrid>
```

If i select any value from select menu the calendars are not rendered for the first time even though the panelGrid rendered attribute is set to true in the backend but if i refresh the page then they are rendered.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue regarding reRendering components with `rendered` attribute directly, when i say directly means what did you just do in your code. Try Wrapping your two panel grid with a parent component like `a4j:outputPanel` and `reRender` that a4j:outputPanel using its id.

Like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="startdate" 
       value="#{commoncontroller.coverDateType}">  
      <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"     
                   action="#controller.dateSelectionChanged}" 
                   reRender="box"/>
          <f:selectItems value="#{controller.startDateMap}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

<a4j:outputPanel id="box">
     <h:panelGrid id="startdateone" layout="block" rendered="#{controller.dateOneStatus}">
            <rich:calendar id="date1"                               value="#{controller.covStartDate}" showWeeksBar="false" />
     </h:panelGrid>

     <h:panelGrid id="startdatetwo" layout="block" rendered="#{controller.dateTwoStatus}">
            <rich:calendar id="date2"                               value="#{controller.covStartDate2}" showWeeksBar="false" />
     </h:panelGrid>

</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Hope this helps.
-cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ellie. Yeah I was doing like that only earlier but asked to eliminate using richFaces components as max as possible. So tried in this way. But got succeeded by using conditional css for panelGrid.
<h:panelGrid id="startdatetwo" layout="block" styleClass="#{commoncontroller.heallaunchervo.coverSDFromStatus ? 'hl-calendarClass-render' : 'hl-calendarClass-renderNot'}">>
            <rich:calendar id="date2"                               value="#{controller.covStartDate2}" showWeeksBar="false" />
     </h:panelGrid>